# Can I deploy my existing API on Amazon web service without using swagger?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I tried deploying API on Amazon API Gateway, but there it is asking Swagger file. Where we get this Swagger file and how to modify my existing API. Can I deploy my existing API on Amazon web service without using swagger.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Specifically, what do you mean, deploy your "existing" API?

Comment: deploy means like put my api (microservice ) on any aws service

Comment: Yes, I understand that point.  But you refer to an "existing" API without defining the sense in which that API "exists" or why that existence is specifically relevant, including what platform/framework the existing API was built on.  If you want to automatically build an API in API Gateway from some kind of template, the choices are Swagger and CloudFormation. If you want to build it manually, you can use the console.  If none of these things are what you want, then it is not clear what kind of functionality you are expecting, in order to be able to do what you are trying to do.